# need self to set all constants of a swift class in init

Tags: swift, self, initializer

I have a Swift class that has a constant ivar (are they called instance constants now?). To set the value to this constant, I need to call an initializer of the desired object and pass itself. However, I am not allowed to as I need to initialize all values first, then call `super.init()` and after that I am allowed to access `self`. So what to do in this case?

```
class Broadcaster: NSObject, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {

    let broadcastID: NSUUID
    let bluetoothManager: CBPeripheralManager

    init(broadcastID: NSUUID) {
        self.broadcastID = broadcastID

        let options: Dictionary<NSString, AnyObject> = [ CBPeripheralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true ]
        self.bluetoothManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: options) // error: 'self' used before super.init call

        super.init()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### UPDATE for Swift 1.2 and later

Unfortunately, it doesn’t seem to be possible any more to have `bluetoothManager` as a constant. Starting from Swift 1.2, in an initializer, constant properties can only assign a value once. This doesn’t allow us to start with a `nil` value by declaring it as an optional and change it later in the initialization process. Here’s the updated version with `bluetoothManager` as a variable.

```
class Broadcaster: NSObject, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {

    let broadcastID: NSUUID
    var bluetoothManager: CBPeripheralManager!

    init(broadcastID: NSUUID) {
        self.broadcastID = broadcastID
        super.init()
        let options: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [ CBPeripheralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true ]
        self.bluetoothManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: options)
    }
}
```

#### Original answer

You could use implicitly unwrapped optional here (for `bluetoothManager`) and assign the value to it after `super.init()`:

```
class Broadcaster: NSObject, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {

    let broadcastID: NSUUID
    let bluetoothManager: CBPeripheralManager!

    init(broadcastID: NSUUID) {
        self.broadcastID = broadcastID
        super.init()
        let options: Dictionary<NSString, AnyObject> = [ CBPeripheralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true ]
        self.bluetoothManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: options)
    }
}
```

Because `bluetoothManager` is an optional, by the time `super.init()` is called, all properties are initialized (`bluetoothManager` is implicitly initialized with `nil`). But because we know that `bluetoothManager` will definitely have the value after the class is initialized, we declare it as explicitly unwrapped to avoid checks when using it.

UPDATE

A property can be declared as constant and still be changed in the initializer. One just has to make sure it has a definite value by the time initialization finishes. This is documented in chapter “Modifying Constant Properties During Initialization” of Swift book.

The situation when a property needs to be initialized with a call where self must be passed from not yet fully initialized object is described in chapter “Unowned References and Implicitly Unwrapped Optional Properties.”

Comment: But then it needs to be a var, instead of a let, doesn't it?

Comment: No, because this all is happening in the initializer, it can still be let. But after the class initialization it won’t be possible to change it.

Comment: See sections called “Modifying Constant Properties During Initialization” and “Unowned References and Implicitly Unwrapped Optional Properties” in Swift book.

Comment: Honestly, it does not seem to make much sense that own instance variables need to be initialized *before* super is being initialized. super does not know anything about my instance vars. So what's the rationale behind it? Vice versa it would make more sense to me.

Comment: @eofster, both parts of your answer not working in the current version.

Comment: Agree with @kelin, this answer no longer works in Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7 (beta 4). Shame, as it was my preferred way of handling this problem. I'm going to go with lazy stored properties.

Comment: @kelin Thanks for the heads-up! Updated the answer to reflect the latest Swift versions.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting up your bluetoothManager as a `@lazy` property and accessing it later on e.g. to `startAdvertising`?

```
@lazy var bluetoothManager: CBPeripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

init() { ... }

func start() {

    self.bluetoothManager.startAdvertising([ "foo" : "bar" ])

}
```

Comment: That's something I already tried. And it works. But that gives away the benefit of having a let. :/