# swift constant implicitly unwrapped optional properties cant't be initialised

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

Here is my simple swift class:

```
class SessionInitTest: NSObject, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {
    let session: NSURLSession!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        session = NSURLSession(configuration: nil, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }
}
```

the Xcode complaints that in the line of `super.init()`:"Property 'self.session' not initialized at super.init call". And the init of session:"Immutable value 'self.session' may only be initialized once". According to [need self to set all constants of a swift class in init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218581/need-self-to-set-all-constants-of-a-swift-class-in-init), why session is not set to nil before `super.init()`?

Comment: Only a *variable* IUO is initialized to `nil`. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30517167/implicitly-unwrapped-optionals-in-swift-does-not-seem-to-work, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956702/unable-to-declare-swift-implicitly-unwrapped-optional-as-a-constant for similar problems.

Comment: So the only solution is to change 'let' to 'var', which substitute the constant by a variable to give a default nil value before 'super.init()'? We can't have a constant 'session' after initialisation?

Comment: `let session` can only be initialized once, and it can only be `nil` before `super.init()` is called because `self` isn't "valid" then. *I* do not know how to do it with a *constant*, perhaps someone else does. Another similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551619/swift-1-2-self-used-before-super-init-call. – It may be that older Swift versions allowed to re-assign a constant within init methods, but that is not possible in Swift 1.2

Comment: Thank you! I thought a default `nil` before `super.init()` will be given to `session` according to "Unowned References and Implicitly Unwrapped Optional Properties." chapter in "Swift Programming Language". It seems this has changed since Swift 1.2